# How can I find what brings load on my system a few days ago?

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

I want to find what bring load on my system. It can be query load or something else. Is it possible to check historical data ? when sql profiler is not working ?

For checking queries that run on my system, I use that both queries below but they are not enough. It is not list my all queries.

```
SELECT  dest.text
FROM    sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS deqs
        CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(deqs.sql_handle) AS dest
WHERE   deqs.last_execution_time > GETDATE()- 1


SELECT SUBSTRING(qt.TEXT, (qs.statement_start_offset/2)+1,
((CASE qs.statement_end_offset
WHEN -1 THEN DATALENGTH(qt.TEXT)
ELSE qs.statement_end_offset
END - qs.statement_start_offset)/2)+1),
qs.execution_count,
qs.total_logical_reads, qs.last_logical_reads,
qs.total_logical_writes, qs.last_logical_writes,
qs.total_worker_time,
qs.last_worker_time,
qs.total_elapsed_time/1000000 total_elapsed_time_in_S,
qs.last_elapsed_time/1000000 last_elapsed_time_in_S,
qs.last_execution_time,
qp.query_plan
FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats qs
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(qs.sql_handle) qt
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_query_plan(qs.plan_handle) qp
where last_execution_time > getdate()-2
ORDER BY qs.total_logical_reads DESC
```

Comment: This query only examines ephemeral cached plans. For forensic analysis, you would need to enable the Query Store or use a trace (server-side SQL or XE trace rather than the Profiler GUI tool).

Comment: The last_execution_time time filter is seen in your query, maybe you can remove and try it again.